# What happens to scanf if the entered value from a file is empty?

Tags: c, input, scanf

I'm using command line to input a text file to a program, which uses the info from the file to display other values accoring what was in that text file.

test.exe < input.txt (Command line)

File looks like this:

> 2
>   abc 123
>   qwe 456

Number 2 tells me how many things program has to read. (Named COUNT in code)

```
double number[MAXVALUE];
char name[MAXVALUE][MAXLENGTH];    
for(i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s %lf", name[i], &number[i]);
    }
```

This what the input code looks like.

Now, what happens is if I put 3 as COUNT, the program will try to read 3 lines and displays the 3rd line as gibberish.
How can I prevent the scanf from operating, if the values entered are non-existant?

I tired `if(scanf(....) != 1)` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: *Undefined behavior* will be invoked when `int*` is passed for `%lf`, which expect `double*`

Comment: Try `if(scanf(....) != 2)` after matching format and type of variable for storeing, because there are 2 elements to read via one `scanf()`.

Comment: I changed the int to double, I typed it wrong,

Comment: if(scanf(....) != 2) did not work, it is still filling the gaps with random stuff.

Comment: And also initialize both `name[i]` and `number[i]` before `scanf()`. Why using `MAXVALUE` and `MAXNAME` as two different constants (should be the same value) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "initialize both name[i] and number[i] before scanf()"?
Also, I fixed the MAXVALUE and MAXNAME. I mistyped again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, avoid invoking *undefined behavior* `%lf` is for reading `double`, not `int`.

Then, the return value of `scanf()` is useful for checking if reading is successful.

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.21.6.4 The scanf function, paragraph 3:

> The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input
>   failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed.
>   Otherwise, the scanf function returns the number of input items
>   assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the
>   event of an early matching failure.

Here is an example of improved code:

```
double number[MAXVALUE];
char name[MAXNAME][MAXLENGTH];    
for(i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    {
        if (scanf("%s %lf", name[i], &number[i]) != 2)
            {
                fputs("read error\n", stderr);
                exit(1); /* stdlib.h should be included to use this */
            }
    }
```

Comment: I modified your code a bit, and got it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a while loop to iterate as long as two items have been scanned. Increment `i` and check to make sure it is less than COUNT or MAXVALUE. `i` will then have the number of elements completed in the arrays.

```
double number[MAXVALUE] = {0.0};
char name[MAXVALUE][MAXLENGTH] = {{ '\0'}};
int i = 0;
while ( ( scanf("%s %lf", name[i], &number[i])) == 2)
{
    i++;
    if ( i >= COUNT || i >= MAXVALUE)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first answer suited me better, thanks for the advice!

Comment: Minor weakness: Should `COUNT <= 0`, `i >= COUNT` test is too late.